# how to pass static variables of class as argument in c#

Tags: c#, class, properties, static

I am trying access properties of particular inbulit class in c# but i am not getting how to pass a class static variable and pass as an argument to a method.

Here is the class I want to pass as argument:

```
public class PageSize
{
    //
    public static readonly Rectangle A0;
    //
    public static readonly Rectangle A1;
}
```

Now I have method where i want to pass the variables of the above class as argument like this:

```
public void NewExportToPDFforLetter(StringWriter sw, string FileName, PageSize s )
{
    //s = new PageSize();
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(s.A0, 30f, 30f, 30f, 30f);
}
```

I am getting error at s.A0. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Remove `static` keyword from `A0` and `A1`

Comment: Why are the properties static?

Comment: Or keep static and reference them as PageSize.A0 etc.

Comment: No I cant edit pagesize class @FCin

Comment: Use the class name.field name: PageSize.A0, PageSize.A1. Since they are read only they need to be initialized inline or in the static constructor.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I have method where i want to pass the variables of the above class as argument like this: `public void NewExportToPDFforLetter(StringWriter sw, string FileName, PageSize s )`

And why would you want to do that? `PageSize` is *already accesible* inside `NewExportToPDFforLetter` without the need to pass it as an argument:

```
public void NewExportToPDFforLetter(
    StringWriter sw, 
    string FileName)
{
      var a0 = PageSize.A0; //accesible as long as `Page` is accesible:
                            //public class, internal in same assembly, etc.

      //...
}
```

If `PageSize` is not accesible from wherever `NewExportToPDFforLetter` is implemented, then you wouldn't be able to pass it as an argument to begin with, so the option  you are considering is simply unecessary.

Comment: No I want to pass this as an argument because value might change as required.

Comment: @abhishek So what if the value changes? I fail to see the difference. You seem to be misunderstanding what `static` really is.

Comment: The class which i am using is the system class and I won't be able to change so this question arised

Comment: @abhishek I'm having trouble following your train of thought here. What does using custom values have to do with anything? If you need values other than the ones defined in `PageSize` then use them! How is `PageSize` even relevant in that scenario?

Comment: See method does not know about the pagesize to give so i am passing argument in the method which will tell pagesize, now how to pass this var and convert it to typeof pagesize

Comment: If i write this directly Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30f, 30f, 30f, 30f); then it will be constant but i dont want to make it constant

Comment: @abhishek Ah, ok, I understand now. What is the type of `PageSize.A0`? Is it `Size`, `PaperSize`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the properties static, you can access them directly using `PageSize.A0` and `PageSize.A1`.

If you want to access them from an instance, you will have to remove the static declaration of the properties.

Answer (score 1):

Since static class variables are not part of an instance, you should not use the instance.property syntax but classname.property.

Thus change

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(s.A0, 30f, 30f, 30f, 30f);
```

to

```
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A0, 30f, 30f, 30f, 30f);
```

However, it's not visible, but probably you do not want to use static. In that case instead of the above change, you have to remove the statics by changing

```
public static readonly Rectangle A0;
//
public static readonly Rectangle A1;
```

to

```
public readonly Rectangle A0;
//
public readonly Rectangle A1;
```

Comment: Can i do like this? Var a0=PageSize.A0; before calling method and then pass this var as argument to the method

Comment: Yes, but you also can do it directly. But with var a0=PageSize.A0, the effect will be the same.

Comment: No actually this method does not know about the pagesize to give so the argument in the method will tell pagesize now how to pass this var and convert it to typeof pagesize

Answer (score 0):

You need to access A0 with `PageSize.A0` instead of `s.A0`

Answer (score 0):

This is the way you can do this

```
var size= PageSize.A4;
NewExportToPDFforLetter(stringWriter, "Application Approval Letter", HttpContext.Current.Response,(Rectangle)size);

public void NewExportToPDFforLetter(StringWriter sw, string FileName, HttpResponse Response, Rectangle s )
{
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(s, 30f, 30f, 30f, 30f);
}
```